# Displaying errors from Zeppelin on Amazon EMR

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm running [Apache Zeppelin on AWS EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-realtime-data-from-amazon-kinesis-streams-using-zeppelin-and-spark-streaming/) for the first time and I'm unable to see the errors after running code.  The only thing I see is the status changes from **Running** to **ERROR**.

[image]

I have also checked the Hadoop Resource Manager and the logs do not contain any errors.

I would assume that Zeppelin should display the errors in the results window.  Is this not the correct assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same issue with emr-5.0.3. This is a known bug. Switched to emr-5.2.0 and it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

The error should be displayed.

BTW What EMR version are you using?

I just tested Zeppelin Tutorial in EMR-5.2.0 and it's working well.

Comment: I'm using emr-5.0.3

Comment: So I am getting errors from SparkSQL but not Spark Scala

Comment: I started running Zeppelin on my localhost and it works as expected.

Comment: I just tested emr-5.0.3 and it doesn't work so maybe you need to upgrade your EMR.

Sorry for not helping.

Answer (score 1):

Zeppelin behaves like this when Spark and Hadoop are not running. Maybe it's simple as that.

Comment: I'm able to get results back when there is no error so it should be running.

Comment: Maybe your interpreter is misconfigured. Can you post it? Does it return error while using a specific interpreter e.g. %pyspark? Is the spark.home set?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit interpreter settings from the menu on the right top corner. Edit `spark` properties section to add `zeppelin.spark.printREPLOutput` as name and set its value to `true`.